# Generate insert statement which has same columns of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have wide table with 100 columns.

I need a SP which takes 100 parameters and then does the  insert.

I know how to do this manually. But having the table definition and knowing that SP parameters will have exact same name of the table columns,  can you think of a better/faster way to generate this stored procedure?

Comment: why have an SP at all if it's just doing an insert?

Comment: Can the solution use application code? If so, what language?

Comment: @marc, SP does more than insert(like validations) but other parts I can type.

Imagine if this 100 column change into 200, there will be place for mistakes .

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://leansoftware.net/Help/Excel-Database-Tasks/Reference/SQL/Create-Insert-Update-Delete-stored-procedure.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use SQL to write it for you. Check it out and let me know if it needs any tweaks or if you have any questions.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('yourTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE yourTable;

CREATE TABLE yourTable
(
    col1 INT,
    col2 VARCHAR(100),
    col3 NUMERIC(18,2)
)

DECLARE @InputParams    VARCHAR(MAX),
        @InsertColumns  VARCHAR(MAX),
        @InsertParams   VARCHAR(MAX);

WITH CTE_columns
AS
(
    SELECT  COLUMN_NAME,
            UPPER(DATA_TYPE) data_type,     
            '(' + CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')' max_length,
            CASE
                WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('Numeric','Decimal') THEN CONCAT('(',NUMERIC_PRECISION,',',NUMERIC_SCALE,')')
            END prec_scale
        --@InsertColumns = COALESCE(@InsertColumns + ',','') + COLUMN_NAME,
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable'
)

SELECT  @InputParams = COALESCE(@InputParams + ',','') + CONCAT('@',column_name,' ',data_type,max_length,prec_scale),
        @InsertColumns = COALESCE(@InsertColumns + ',','') + COLUMN_NAME,
        @InsertParams = COALESCE(@InsertParams + ',','') + '@'+ COLUMN_NAME 
FROM CTE_columns

SELECT 
'CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.yourProc ' + @InputParams +
' AS 
INSERT INTO yourTable(' + @InsertColumns + ')
VALUES (' + @InsertParams + ');
GO'
```

Results(Formatting isn't great, but it works):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.yourProc @col1 INT,@col2 VARCHAR(100),@col3 NUMERIC(18,2) AS 
INSERT INTO yourTable(col1,col2,col3)
VALUES (@col1,@col2,@col3);
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

For this type of scenario, I like to leverage table types.

First, create the table type:

`CREATE TYPE [YourType] AS TABLE (columns...)`

In C#, populate a `DataTable` "template" by running this query (using a `DataAdapter`):

```
DECLARE @tt AS [YourType]
SELECT * FROM @tt
```

Then add a row to the table and cycle through the columns to add the necessary values.

Then pass the datatable as a parameter into your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [YourProc]
@tt [YourType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
--do stuff
END
```

An added benefit of this approach is that you can pass multiple records into the procedure with a single call.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably quickly modify this for your needs:

```
    Declare @tableName nvarchar(100) = 'aspnet_Membership'
    Declare @objectName nvarchar(100) = 'Membership'

    DECLARE @newLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

    Declare @columnName nvarchar(50)
    Declare @dataType nvarchar(50)
    Declare @characterLength int 
    Declare @isNullableString varchar(3) 
    Declare @ordinalPosition int
    Declare @firstSortOrder smallint


    Declare @variableTableCreateCode nvarchar(max) = ''
    Declare @variableTableDataTypeCode nvarchar(128)
    Declare @variableTableSelectCode001 nvarchar(max) = ''
    Declare @variableTableSelectCode002 nvarchar(max) = ''
    Declare @varableTableInsertIntoCode nvarchar(max) = ''

    Declare tbl_ColumnCursor Cursor For 
    Select  colSchema.COLUMN_NAME, colSchema.DATA_TYPE, colSchema.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, colSchema.IS_NULLABLE , colSchema.ORDINAL_POSITION , FirstSortOrder = CASE WHEN PrimaryKeyDerived.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2  END
    from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS colSchema

    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
        ,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME
        ,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE

        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

        LEFT OUTER JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
        ON
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME=information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME
        AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME=information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME

        LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
        ON
        information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.TABLE_NAME=information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME
        AND information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME=information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME

        WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'

    ) as PrimaryKeyDerived on colSchema.TABLE_NAME = PrimaryKeyDerived.TABLE_NAME and colSchema.COLUMN_NAME = PrimaryKeyDerived.COLUMN_NAME


    where   colSchema.TABLE_NAME = @tableName 
    Order By    FirstSortOrder , colSchema.ORDINAL_POSITION

        Set @variableTableCreateCode = 'declare @' + @objectName + 'Holder table ( ' + @objectName + 'SurrogateKey int , ' 
        Set @variableTableSelectCode001 = 'INSERT INTO @' + @objectName + 'Holder ( '
        Set @variableTableSelectCode002 = ' SELECT ' 
        Set @varableTableInsertIntoCode = 'INSERT INTO '+@tableName+' ( '


    Open tbl_ColumnCursor
    Fetch Next From tbl_ColumnCursor Into @ColumnName, @dataType, @characterLength, @isNullableString, @ordinalPosition , @firstSortOrder

    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin

        print '/@ColumnName/'
        print @ColumnName 
        print ''

        print '/@@dataType/'
        print @dataType 
        print ''    


        print '/@@@isNullableString/'
        print @isNullableString 
        print ''            







            Select @variableTableDataTypeCode = 
                case 
                    when @dataType like '%char%' and @characterLength  = -1 Then
                        @dataType+'(max)'                   
                    when @dataType like '%char%' and @characterLength  = 1 Then
                        @dataType+'('+convert(varchar(32), @characterLength)+')'
                    When (@dataType like '%char%') Or (@dataType = 'xml') Or (@dataType like '%text%') Then
                        @dataType+'('+convert(varchar(32), @characterLength)+')'
                    Else @dataType
                End


            Set @variableTableCreateCode = @variableTableCreateCode + ' [' + @columnName + '] ' + @variableTableDataTypeCode +','



            select @variableTableSelectCode002  = @variableTableSelectCode002 + 'T.MyEntity.value(''@' + @columnName + ''', '''+@variableTableDataTypeCode+''') AS ' + @columnName + ','    



        Fetch Next From tbl_ColumnCursor Into @ColumnName, @dataType, @characterLength , @isNullableString , @ordinalPosition , @firstSortOrder

    End


    Close tbl_ColumnCursor
    Deallocate tbl_ColumnCursor




    if(DATALENGTH(@variableTableCreateCode) > 0)
    BEGIN
        select @variableTableCreateCode = LEFT(@variableTableCreateCode, LEN(@variableTableCreateCode) -1)
    END

    if(DATALENGTH(@variableTableSelectCode002) > 0)
    BEGIN
        select @variableTableSelectCode002 = LEFT(@variableTableSelectCode002, LEN(@variableTableSelectCode002) -1)
    END 





    Set @variableTableCreateCode = @variableTableCreateCode + @newLineChar + ' ) '



    select @variableTableCreateCode


    select @variableTableSelectCode001 = @variableTableSelectCode001 + ( SELECT 
              MyColumns = STUFF
              (
                (
                  SELECT ', [' + r.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS r
                   WHERE r.TABLE_NAME = tabs.TABLE_NAME
                   ORDER BY r.ORDINAL_POSITION
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
                1,1,''
              )
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS tabs
            /* Optional WHERE Clause */
            WHERE 
                tabs.TABLE_NAME = @tableName
             )

    select @variableTableSelectCode001 = @variableTableSelectCode001 + ' ) '+@newLineChar            
    select @variableTableSelectCode002 = @variableTableSelectCode002 + ' FROM @xmldata.nodes(''RootElement/' + @tableName + 'Elements/' + @tableName + 'Element'') AS T(MyEntity); '
    select @variableTableSelectCode001 + @variableTableSelectCode002



    select @varableTableInsertIntoCode = @varableTableInsertIntoCode + ( SELECT 
              MyColumns = STUFF
              (
                (
                  SELECT ', [' + r.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS r
                   WHERE r.TABLE_NAME = tabs.TABLE_NAME
                   ORDER BY r.ORDINAL_POSITION
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
                1,1,''
              )
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS tabs
            WHERE 
                tabs.TABLE_NAME = @tableName
             )

    select @varableTableInsertIntoCode = @varableTableInsertIntoCode + ' ) SELECT ' 

    select @varableTableInsertIntoCode = @varableTableInsertIntoCode + ( SELECT 
              MyColumns = STUFF
              (
                (
                  SELECT ', holder.[' + r.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
                   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS r
                   WHERE r.TABLE_NAME = tabs.TABLE_NAME
                   ORDER BY r.ORDINAL_POSITION
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
                1,1,''
              )
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS tabs
            WHERE 
                tabs.TABLE_NAME = @tableName
             )  


    select @varableTableInsertIntoCode = @varableTableInsertIntoCode + ' from @' + @objectName + 'Holder holder where not exists ( select null from ' +@tableName+ '  realTable where realTable.Name = holder.Name and realTable.IsDeleted = holder.IsDeleted ) '


    select @varableTableInsertIntoCode






SELECT 
  tabs.TABLE_NAME, 
  MyColumns = STUFF
  (
    (
      SELECT ', alias.[' + r.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS r
       WHERE r.TABLE_NAME = tabs.TABLE_NAME
       ORDER BY r.ORDINAL_POSITION
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    1,1,''
  )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS tabs
/* Optional WHERE Clause */
WHERE 
    tabs.TABLE_NAME = @tableName
ORDER BY tabs.TABLE_NAME;
```